# How to get rid of OSGi bundle's properties that are not exist in their corresponding configuration ("service.pid", etc.)?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, apache-servicemix

I have the class similar to the following:

```
@Component(configurationPid = "foo.bar", configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public class MyClass {

    @Activate
    public void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) throws Exception {
        for (String property : properties.keySet()) {
            if (!isValidProperty(property)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown property: " + property);
            }
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

The `properties` map must contain the properties from the corresponding configuration source (e.g. a file provided by an user). And it is, but it also contains some properties that are not really exist (`service.pid`, `felix.fileinstall.dir`, etc.), so my program is broken. I want to get rid of them somehow.
I tried to use `ConfigurationAdmin.getConfiguration.getProperties` and also blueprint `cm-properties` but this gives the same effect.
I can't hardcode the names of the properties to exclude, because I don't know what they are.
Is there any means to tell the OSGi runtime not to put them at all in my map?
I'm doing this using ServiceMix's OSGi support (which is essentially Karaf, Felix, and Aries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to exclude these artificial properties but I agree this is pretty bad.

You can open an issue and the [Apache felix project jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX).

Comment: These properties are mandated by the spec so I am not sure how Felix could 'legally' get rid of them

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the properties you don't like/understand. The system is designed so that the party doing the configuration can add any property and that property will be passed to your component and thus be a service property on your component's service. Removing the properties you, the component developer, don't understand is overly restrictive. You would remove the ability of someone in the deployment process from decorating your service in a way meaningful to someone else.